# NodeJS Switch between multiple Nodemon Config files

Tags: node.js, nodemon

I have a nodejs project which is using nodemon for providing environment variables when running locally. I have a need to have the developers easily switch between two different nodemon config files (two different sets of environment variables). But I can't see a way to specify a config file for nodemon. How can I accomplish this.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the config file using the `--config` flag:

https://github.com/remy/nodemon#config-files